# Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match

Tags: java, image, awt

Please help me.Any help would be worth. Right now I am getting strange exception

---

```
ERROR - Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color      space components do not match
at java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp.filter(ColorConvertOp.java:460)
at   com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.acceptPixels(JPEGImageReader.java:1169)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1137)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:948)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
```

---

Below is the code i used.Urgent help is required.

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage image1   =  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(root_url+"/Documents/SSOImage/"+linkInfo.get(FieldNames.IMAGE)));
```

[image]

Comment: SOunds like an improper input file for the "picture" -- what format is that picture supposed to be in?

Comment: Can you provide an image where this error message occurs?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII .You are right but the picture seems quite fine.

Comment: I have got solution anyways there is issue with the image quality. It is due to some pixels scattered around.Also,can't attach image as it is confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was issue with the image quality. It was due to some pixels scattered around. 
Also,can't attach image as it is confidential.

Answer (score 0):

i hit this issue before when i convert pdf to tif, cause by the picture in the pdf.
the picture's color space is CMYK.
refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3637?filter=-2