# PDFBox 2.0.20 - Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am seeing the below exception when converting a PDF pages to image using pdfbox 2.0.20.

Here is the code which is throwing exception :

```
...
BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
....
```

*PdfBox Version* : **2.0.20**

*Exception* :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match
at java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp.filter(ColorConvertOp.java:493)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.acceptPixels(JPEGImageReader.java:1292)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1259)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1062)
at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.DCTFilter.decode(DCTFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSInputStream.create(COSInputStream.java:80)
at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createInputStream(COSStream.java:246)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:241)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.createInputStream(PDImageXObject.java:776)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.from8bit(SampledImageReader.java:373)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.SampledImageReader.getRGBImage(SampledImageReader.java:226)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject.getImage(PDImageXObject.java:479)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawImage(PageDrawer.java:1139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:67)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:932)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:510)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:484)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:271)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:321)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:243)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:229)

I think Image bands and components are not matching while converting one of the PDF pages to images.

I found the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721959/numbers-of-source-raster-bands-and-source-color-space-components-do-not-match) posted in the channel , but I can not access the [jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3637?filter=-2) which is mentioned this post.

Please share your thoughts how to fix this issue.

Comment: oops, sorry, I didn't want to close it (I have too much power?!), just to flag / suggest it as duplicate. But the point is that you should use the twelvemonkeys plugin, it's great. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826608/535646

Comment: Also update to 2.0.29.